# How to match two conditions in one match URL in rewrite rule?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to add two conditions in one match URL in rewrite rule? For example I need to add trailing slash and lowercase in URL. I don't want to add two different rules for this because this causes to make two 301 redirections. I want to do this with single rule. Can anybody provide help with this in ASP.NET? [Click here for example]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Please show what you've tried so far and where you are having a problem.

Comment: I tried the things which in image

Comment: where's the image?

Comment: i don't know i have uploaded, let me edit this again

Comment: How to edit this question to add image again?

Comment: @SmartRocker - To edit, click on "edit" above between "share" and "close".